# convert strings with sign to float and float back to string

Tags: java, string, floating-point

I have string representation of percentage change of a stock quote in the format `+6.63` and some in `-0.06`, which i need to check is it a positive change or negative...

after splitting the string on + and - sign,

i can apply 
     `Float.parseFloat(stringWithNoSign);`

but is there a way to extract the string as signed and convert to float

Comment: This isn't clear; why can't you just do `Float.parseFloat(originalString)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `Float.parseFloat(stringWithSign)` to convert back and forth.

If you still have problems with `parseFloat` you should consider your [locale separator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9113067/1447087)  and try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4323628/1447087).

Comment: yes got it... thnx...

Answer (score 0):

`Float.parseFloat()` will parse the correct floating point number included the sign. This method internally uses `Float.valueOf()` which in turn transforms any valid java language float literal into a float type, of course including the ones you are dealing with.

Some info:

- [Documentation for `Float.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29)
- [Java Language Specification - Floating Point Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2)

Answer (score 0):

`Float.parseFloat()` will handle negative numbers, but `float` is imprecise, possibly leading to output with repeating decimals, where none existed in the original string, due to rounding issues internal to the way floats are stored.

For *exact* numbers, use the `BigDecimal` class, which will input, output and perform arithmetic without loss of precision.