# Android - parse String longitude to float causes error

Tags: android, string, type-conversion

I need to convert my CMS data (which are provided as Strings) to float value, but I am getting exception

```
NumberFormatException: invalid float value: "16.385837"
```

The code looks like:

```
Double.valueOf(myString.trim()).doubleValue();
```

I've also tried like this:

```
Double.parseDouble(myString).doubleValue();
```

but i'm getting the same message. Do you have any idea what is wrong ?!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you messed up with locale, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4323628/1387438

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
  String s = "16.385837";
  Double d = Double.parseDouble(s); 
  System.out.println(d);// which will prints 16.385837
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // p did not contain a valid double
}
```

Comment: no. it will print correct result. may be your `myString` has wrong value. once check that value by printing System.out.println(myString+" "+myString.length());

Comment: check the length of the string and string value.

Comment: for all strings that are causing parse error, length is one more greater than real length visible on the console. May it mean that there is some extra code at the end of the string causing the problem ?

Comment: yes. if there is space then it won't be considered for parsing. which results parse error..

Comment: it have to work. If it doesn't work then you messed up something probably with locale. Are you sure that string contains "16.385837" not for example "16,385837" (you use Polish locale)? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4323628/1387438

Comment: i've checked - there is one extra char at the end of the string causing this problem. i'll try to substring wrong strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = e1.getText().toString();
Float f= Float.parseFloat(s);
```

use this code this will helps you

put your value on place of s; then you can parse string to float

Comment: There is no method getText() for String object, it is not a View subclass

Comment: i specially add one line put your value on place of s

Comment: there was another problem, my string contained some extra char at the end of it, and it was causing the problem. I've surrounded this block of code with try/catch and in catch block I substring this value, cutting off the last character. It works fine but thanks for help!

Comment: the right answer that helped me with that problem is on the top of this thread but I voted up for your answer too

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf("16.385837"));
```

Answer (score 0):

try

`Double.parseDouble(myString)  not .doubleValue();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try {
        Double d = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf("16.385837")); 
        System.out.println(d);
     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         // Handle The Exception During  Parsing
     }
```