# (Java + Android) Parsing string to float strange error

Tags: java, android, string, parsing

This may sound like a trivial question, but I'm having a really hard time trying to figure it out. Basically I'm sending a string from my Android to my PC. All the connection is ok, and the string is transfered successfully. This is the Android code (sends string to computer):

```
  try
  {
    println(scSocket + "");
    if (scSocket!=null) 
    {
    SendReceiveBytes sendReceiveBT = new SendReceiveBytes(scSocket);
    String red = rotZ + " \n";
    byte[] myByte = stringToBytesUTFCustom(red);
    sendReceiveBT.write(myByte);
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    println(e);
  }
```

Where rotZ is what I want to send, it is a "float" value. I need to put the " \n" on the end of the message so that it will be recognized as a full message on the PC. So far so good. Now I want to read this on my PC, which is achieved by:

```
  //BlueTooth
  String lineRead = "";
  try
  {
    lineRead = new String(sampleSPPServer.readFromDevice());
    if(lineRead != null && !lineRead.isEmpty())
    {
      String lineTransf = lineRead.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").replace(" ", "").replace("\"", "").trim();
      println("LineTransf: " + lineTransf);
      rotZ += 0.01*(Float.parseFloat(lineTransf));
      println("Zrotation: " + rotZ); //Never gets here, throws and error before...
    }
    else
      rotZ += 0;
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    println("Exception: " + e);
  }
```

Which gives me the error:

```
NumberFormatException: invalid float value: "1.1400002"
```

In my code you can see I check for null, empty, etc. So that's not the problem. I've already tried:

```
  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
  rotZ += 0.01*(nf.parse(lineTransf).floatValue());
```

Got the same result... In stackoverflow there is a similar question:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562014/android-parse-string-longitude-to-float-causes-error)

There is one more strange thing, If I try the code:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < lineTransf.length(); i++)
    println(lineTransf.substring(i,1));
```

I get that the string's length is 19, but it only prints the first two and gives the message:

```
Exception: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

Even more strange thing, when I did ctrl-c, ctrl-v on the number "1.1400002" that appears in the console, it only pastes "1" here on stack overflow.
I know that the number is right, but somewhere the conversion is not. I think that's because the string is sent as a byte and read as a String, but how do I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around, but I really, really would like an explanation (if possible), because this is just too ugly... I changed the code to:

```
//BlueTooth
  String lineRead = "";
  try
  {
    lineRead = new String(sampleSPPServer.readFromDevice());
    if(lineRead != null && !lineRead.isEmpty())
    {
      String lineTransf = lineRead.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").replace(" ", "").replace("\"", "").trim();
      println("LineTransf: " + lineTransf + " " + lineTransf.length());
      String lastTry = "";
      for(int i = 0; i < lineTransf.length(); i++)
      {
        if(lineTransf.charAt(i) != ' ' && lineTransf.charAt(i) != '\u0000')
        {
          println(lineTransf.charAt(i));
          lastTry += lineTransf.charAt(i);
        }
      }
      println("LastTry: " + lastTry);
      rotZ += 0.01*(Float.parseFloat(lastTry));
      println("Zrotation: " + rotZ);
    }
    else
      rotZ += 0;
    //System.out.println("Line Read:" + lineRead);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    println("Exception: " + e);
  }
```

I'm basically creating a new String called lastTry and then checking if each of the bluetooth read characters are not empty(?) null(?) (since I'm testing for:)

```
if(lineTransf.charAt(i) != ' ' && lineTransf.charAt(i) != '\u0000')
```

And if they pass this test I individually "assemble" the lastTry String. It **seems** that the bluetooth is sending a null character between each of the characters of the whole string. I don't understand why this happens and it actually consumes some time while reading the incoming string. I really would love another answer if someone have another idea...

Answer (score 0):

Nothing strange. that's the expected behavior of `substring`. It throws an  `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, if the `startIndex` is negative, the `endIndex` is greater than the string's length or if `startIndex` is greater the `endIndex` (which is your case). To me it looks like you want to print the char at index. Try with

```
for(int i = 0; i < lineTransf.length(); i++)
    println(lineTransf.charAt(i));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right, I made the change, and it prints: lineTransf: 1.8399 and then 1 . 8 3 9 9, but still gives me the length 19 and the Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

Comment: no worries. Which part is not working? Both "1.8399" and "1.1400002" are valid *parsable*-like float

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm not understanding. The line println("LineTransf: " + lineTransf); prints those numbers, but  rotZ += 0.01*(Float.parseFloat(lineTransf)); gives me the NumberFormatException no matter what i do.

Comment: I see. But also those 19 chars are strange, aren't they? Can you print `println("LineTransf: " + lineTransf + " size " + lineTransf.length());` ?

Comment: It prints exactly this to the console:
LineTransf: 9.959991 size 15
For other numbers, it prints the number and a bigger size (just like above)