# NumberFormatException when parsing a Double from string

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

Long story short here is my code that throws the number format exception:-

```
String percenta = "6.415‏";
holder.setPercent(Double.parseDouble(percenta));
```

I've tried a also Double.valueOf() but none of them work, still throws the same exception

here is the exception message

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6.415‏"
```

what seems to be the problem here ?

**EDIT**

so the problem is in my encoding after all, how do i change that,
I am using JSOUP to parse a page and it is supposed to be UTF-8,
is Double.parseDouble not UTF-8 friendly ?

Comment: `<pun>` Shouldn't it be *«Double story short»*? `</pun>`

Comment: @afsantos go home, you're ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
Number number = format.parse("6.415");
double d = number.doubleValue();
```

This may happen because of your internal [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) specification.

In order to verify it, check if it works:

```
String percenta = "6,415‏";
holder.setPercent(Double.parseDouble(percenta));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess it is because your computer is running a non-English locale.  Try Double.valueOf("6.415") for the English locale, or see [Best way to parseDouble with comma as decimal separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323599/best-way-to-parsedouble-with-comma-as-decimal-separator) for more info on parsing.

Answer (score 2):

The choice of variable name `percenta` suggests that you're using the locale `sk-SK`.

The decimal separator for the locale is `,` and not `.`.

Answer (score 1):

`6.415` is a valid value and should not throw a `NumberFormatException`.
Check your encoding. When I copy-pasted your code, got error while saving it.

[image]

Comment: how to check my encoding ? and how can I change the encoding of my characters ?

Answer (score 0):

The encoding for the 'percenta = "6.415‏"' is not supported for Double to parse.

Please check the below error when I tried to copy your code.

[image]

Comment: Why `6.415` is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the 6.415. It seems you are using keyboard that is not having compliant character encoding.