# How can I make a JTextField accept double value with comma as the separator?

Tags: java, swing, double, jtextfield

Title says it all. I get NumberFormatException for obvious reason. I want to input double values to my JTextFields with using comma instead of a dot as the decimal separator since I'm north European.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event2) {

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);

    double firstW = Double.parseDouble(firstWeight.getText());
    double secondW = Double.parseDouble(secondWeight.getText());

    double outcome = (firstW - secondW);

    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    JLabel result = new JLabel();
    result.setText(nf.format(outcome) +" kg" );

    add(result);
    setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Unless I missed something, I don't see anything in the JTextField class that does any analysis of the text that the user enters.  In particular, I don't think JTextField tries to convert text to numbers.  So you must be using a method in some other class.  Please clarify how you're doing the conversion, and probably show the code that is supposed to produce the `double` value.

Comment: Added some code to the question. The result however, is shown in the correct, german form with comma.

Comment: possible duplicate of [best way to parseDouble with comma as decimal separator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323599/best-way-to-parsedouble-with-comma-as-decimal-separator)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I couldn't implement that solution to my situation when using JTextField and JLabel.

Comment: Why aren’t you just using `new JFormattedTextField(nf)`?

Comment: Your code sets `nf` to a `NumberFormat` object that specifies German, but you don't use `nf` to parse the input, so `Double.parseDouble` has no way to know that it's supposed to parse in German format.  Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `NumberFormat` you already have all you need. Just use `NumberFormat.parse` instead of `Double.parse`. But it’s even easier when you use a `JFormattedTextField` (guess what it does from the class name. Pass the desired `NumberFormat` to the constructor, i.e. `new JFormattedTextField(nf)`. The `JFormattedTextField` has a `getValue` method which returns the last valid edit, in case of your `NumberFormat` it will be a `Number`.

*Know your libraries*

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the comma with dot when you press the button:

`String text=textfield.getText().replace(",",".");`

and then you can use the text variable, not the textfield.getText();

Answer (score -1):

Iterate through text field when submitting and if comma occurs replace with decimal. After the loop convert string to double