# Removing a decimal point in java

Tags: java

I am wanting to store an integer named Amount, I want it to be stored in pence so if the user entered 11.45 it would be stored as 1145. What is the best way to remove the decimal point? Should I be using decimalFormatting in Java?

**Edit:**

It is entered in string format, was going to covert it to an int. I will give one of your solutions ago and let you know if it works but not sure which one would be the best.. Thanks everyone.

Comment: multiply it by 100?

Comment: Is the user input in the form of a string or is it some numeric type. If the latter, what type?

Comment: Please give us some feedback. What solutions are/aren't working? Which ones are on the right track for you?

Comment: it is entered as a string but should be an int, so I have convereted it into an int.  using: -int tranAmount = Integer.valueOf(transactionAmount);

Answer (score 0):

times it by 100 and cast as int. Use decimal formatting is double / float are too inaccurate which they may be for money

Comment: This only works if there are exactly two digits to the right of the radix point.

Answer (score -1):

If the user input is in the form of a string (and the format has been verified), then you can strip out the decimal point and interpret the result as an integer (or leave it as a string without the decimal point).

```
String input = "11.45";
String stripped = input.replace(".", ""); // becomes "1145"
int value = Integer.parseInt(stripped);
```

If it's a `float` already, then just multiply by 100 and cast, as @user1281385 suggests.

Comment: @MartinMajer - OP said that the input was in a particular format.

Comment: "if the user entered 11.45" doesn't mean that he can't enter 11.4500. I think good solution is just to multiply it by 100 and cast to int.

Comment: @MartinMajer - That requires converting to a float or double first. I was trying to avoid the possible rounding errors that might cost.

Answer (score -1):

**Tested and works**. Even if the user enters a number *without* a decimal, it will keep it as such.

```
double x = 11.45; // number inputted

String s = String.valueOf(x); // String value of the number inputted
int index = s.indexOf("."); // find where the decimal is located

int amount = (int)x; // intialize it to be the number inputted, in case its an int

if (amount != x) // if the number inputted isn't an int (contains decimal)
    // multiply it by 10 ^ (the number of digits after the decimal place)
    amount = (int)(x * Math.pow(10,(s.length() - 1 - index)));

System.out.print(amount); // output is 1145

// if x was 11.4500, the output is 1145 as well
// if x was 114500, the output is 114500
```

Comment: @MartinMajer To have it work for all cases. It's not complicated. Just read the comments.

Comment: It's complicated if you can just multiply the number by 100, round it and convert to int.

Comment: @MartinMajer That's a horrible solution. It doesn't cover all cases. What if the user enters 1.45? Then what? This isn't complicated. Read the comments and understand. Took me 2 minutes. All the OP has to do is copy and paste and it will work for **all** cases.

Comment: @MartinMajer It's 4 lines of code for the solution. That is definitely not complicated.

Comment: If the user enters 1.45, then multiplying and simple rounding + conversion will return 145, which is correct, I suppose.

Comment: @MartinMajer lol yeah I meant to provide an example with a different in  the fractional numbers. Example is 1.5. This isn't the place for semantics. What I've done is better solution.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it. Give me some examples where the simple solution with multiplying by 100 doesn't work and this one does.

Comment: @MartinMajer I just said 1.5. Multiply that by 100 and its *150*. Seriously, stop.

Comment: Seriously, the guy was talking about pence and that means money. And 1.5 pounds isn't 15 pence.

Comment: @MartinMajer You're that immature to -1 my solution *that actually works for all cases* just because he's talking about pence? This solution is generic; yours isn't. If someone enters 11.4, yours will
 give incorrect output. You shouldn't be on this site if that's the reason you downvote a post.

Comment: If you still think that the piece of code you've written is useful, try it with `1.0000000000001` and `1.000000000000000000001`. You will get some really interesting results. And please read something about floating-point numbers, you just cannot handle them this way.

Comment: @MartinMajer again with the semantics. If he was worried out numbers being larger than `2^32 - 1`, (ridiculous semantics) then he can make an if statement to not take in a number that large, or just use an even *more complicated* string method. I know how to handle floating-point numbers. My solution is still better than any others on this page. I don't know why it's so hard for you to give someone credit. "Why so complicated?" Really? And you're going into floating-point numbers.

Comment: @mikeyaworski I have used your code(just changed the variable names), but it is asking me to initialise the local variable: -double tranAmount;transactionAmount = String.valueOf(tranAmount);transactionAmount.indexOf(".");   int amount = (int)tranAmount; // intialize it to be the number inputted, in case its an int

    if (amount != tranAmount) // if the number inputted isn't an int (contains decimal)
        // multiply it by 10 ^ (the number of digits after the decimal place)
        amount = (int)(tranAmount * Math.pow(10,(transactionAmount.length() - 1 - index)));

Comment: go to this website: http://pastie.org and post your code there. Select `Java` at the top right hand corner and then select `Create Paste`. Copy the link and paste it here.

Answer (score -1):

What about convert to float, multiply by 100 and then convert to int?

```
String pound = "10.45"; // user-entered string
int pence = (int)Math.round(Float.parseFloat(pound) * 100);
```

This might be also useful: [Best way to parseDouble with comma as decimal separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323599/best-way-to-parsedouble-with-comma-as-decimal-separator)