# cast String with period and comma to int

Tags: java

how to cast String with period and comma to int, like

```
String a "9.000,00"
int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

when I run this code, I get an error message : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9.000,00"`

Comment: what do you want to do on the occurrence of `.` or `,`? You want to remove it or replace by `.`?

Comment: I think the first part of your problem is that `int` doesn't contain any fractional precision. What if your `String` was "9.000,01"?

Comment: What do you want the answer to be? `9` or `900000`?

Comment: 9.000,00 is not a number to begin with. Do you mean 9,000.00?

Comment: want the answer to be 900000

Comment: @nafas as far as I know, that's how numbers are formatted in French.

Comment: @Okem Are you sure that `900000` is the right answer? Shouldn't it be `9000`?

Comment: @nafas It is a number and depends on what decimal and thousand sep are... the format from the OP looks french

Comment: @Pshemo you are right. If OP is working for a bank...

Comment: @Okem if you want the answer to be 900000 then this is what u need:  **int b = Integer.parseInt(a.replaceAll(",","").replaceAll("\\.",""));**

Comment: @pbabcdefp neither! nobody knows France here? 9.000,00 is 9000 (which is 9,000.00 in US)

Comment: @AbbéRésina op stated that he wants the number 9.000,00 to be 900000

Comment: @Adz, ok that's cents then

Comment: @Adz But the OP accepted the answer that produces 9000 as output. So either he doesn't know what he wants or what he's doing.

Comment: @AlexisC. he accepted the answer after I made my comment lol. But yes it seems like op doesn't know what he wants!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final String a = "9.000,00";
final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN); // Use German locale for number formats
final Number number = format.parse(a); // Parse the number
int i = number.intValue(); // Get the integer value
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323599/best-way-to-parsedouble-with-comma-as-decimal-separator)

Comment: `(int) Double.parseDouble("9.000,00")` throws a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: @Tom Code is tested :) I can make it prettier, but this is just a PoC... I always use `final`.

Comment: Then you should have notices the problem with `final a` and the reassignment :P. Btw: you don't have to replace the points (the thousand separator), just use a locale that uses them as the thousand separator, like GERMAN.

Comment: The problem with `Locale.FRANCE` is that it doesn't have a default grouping separator `System.out.println(((DecimalFormat) format).getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator());`prints nothing for me. Other locales print the correct separator.

Comment: lots of `final` clutter

Comment: @SteveKuo Your opinion. Luckily there are others as well: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/why-declare-final-variables-inside-methods.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, fixed. Strange thing is in France they use the thousands separator as well (most of the Mediterranean world uses it this way AFAIK).

Comment: @m0skit0 [It looks like a *very new* bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4510618) :D.

Comment: @Tom I found out that `GERMAN` and `FRENCH` work fine, but `GERMANY` and `FRANCE` do not... Go figure why.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get as result `900000` then simply remove all `,` and `.` and parse it with for instance with `Integer.parseInt` or `Long.parseLong` or maybe even better use `BigInteger` if number can be large.

```
String a = "9.000,00";
BigInteger bn = new BigInteger(a.replaceAll("[.,]", ""));
System.out.println(bn);
```

Output: `900000`

---

But if you want to parse `9.000,00` into `9000` (where `,00` part is decimal fraction) then you can use `NumberFormat` with `Locale.GERMANY` which uses form similar to your input: `123.456,78`

```
String a = "9.000,00";
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
Number number = format.parse(a);
double value = number.doubleValue();
//or if you want int
int intValue = number.intValue();
System.out.println(value);
System.out.println(intValue);
```

Output:

```
9000.0
9000
```

Answer (score 2):

To do that, you need to use `java.text.NumberFormat` and `NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE)` (or another compatible `Locale`)

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
        String a = "9.000,00";
        a = a.replaceAll("\\.", "");
        Number number = format.parse(a);
        double d = number.doubleValue();
        int c = (int) Math.floor(d);   
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

prints `9000` as you want ( and now is an `int` ) !

If I print every intermediate step :

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
 import java.util.*;
class test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
   String a = "9.000,00";
   a = a.replaceAll("\\.", "");
   System.out.println(a); // prints 9000,00
   Number number = format.parse(a);
   System.out.println(number); // prints 9000
   double d = number.doubleValue();
   System.out.println(d); // prints 9000.0
   int c = (int) Math.floor(d);   
   System.out.println(c); // prints 9000
}
}
```

so if Okem you want `9000,00` as you're saying in your comment, you just need

```
a = a.replaceAll("\\.", "");
System.out.println(a);
```

which gives you an output of `9000,00`

I hope that helps.

Comment: ... well I doubt the OP wants 9 as the final output.

Comment: I fixed it output is now 9000 and an int !

Comment: .. a bit overkill when you can simply do `int b = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN).parse("9.000,00").intValue();` and by the way all the classes in the lang package are automatically imported so you don't need to specify the import.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am sure there are "shorter" ways to do that :)

Comment: and how to remove the back of the two zero numbers, so when I'm using 'currencyFormat.format(a);' it will be 9.000,00 not 900.000,00 , actually i'm using ID currency format.

Comment: @Okem Please use [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28992401/edit) option (placed under your question post) and describe what exactly are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Okem I don't understand what you're saying, the output of my code if I print every intermediate step is 9000,00
9000
9000.0
9000 ... I don't see any 900.000,00 there !

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
String a = "9.000,00";
a = a.replace(",","");
a = a.replace(".","");
int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
```

Comment: I have edited it. Now, it should give you the desired result.

Comment: No! Even with the edit, this is wrong. Who up-voted this? The edit results in `a` being "900000", which of course parses to 900000.

Comment: I replied as per the OP's comment that he wants 900000. But, later he accepted an answer with 9000. He was not sure I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I think [DecimalFormat.parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)) is the Java 7 API way to go:

```
String  a = "9.000,00";
DecimalFormat foo = new DecimalFormat();
Number bar = foo.parse(a, new ParsePosition(0));
```

After that, you go and be happy with the [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) you just got.

If you want the answer to be 900000 (it doesn't make sense to me, but I'm replying to *your* question) and put that into an **int** go with:

```
int b = Integer.parseInt(a.replaceAll(",","").replaceAll("\\.",""));
```

as already outlined in the comments.