# How to parse "1,234.56" in Java as Double?

Tags: java, double, locale

I am having trouble parsing "1,234.56" in Java, a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323599/best-way-to-parsedouble-with-comma-as-decimal-separator) recommend using French locale in number formatting, but it is parsing the result incorrectly.  Here is what I have:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
Number number = format.parse("1,234.56");
System.out.println(number.doubleValue()); // Should get 1234.56, got 1.234 instead
Number number = format.parse("1,234,567.89");
System.out.println(number.doubleValue());  // Should get 1234567.89
```

Comment: Just so you know, in France, the decimal point is denoted by a comma, not a period. That is not what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`1,234.56` is **not** French notation. (Something like `1.234,56` is).

Change your locale to `Locale.ENGLISH`, `Locale.US`, or similar

Answer (score 2):

French locale has the decimal point represented by a comma. You'll need to use the US locale:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
```

or `Locale.ENGLISH` based on the language:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use string replacement and replace `","` for `""`

```
format.parse(("1,234.56").replace(",", ""));
```

Its messy, but you dont need to solve locale.

Comment: Blindly replace one symbols by another is always bad idea.