# Java - Convert a string to double with 10 or more decimals

Tags: java

How do I convert a string such as  `40,123.012345678901`  to a `double`?

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("40,123.012345678901");
```

throws a number format exception.

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to remove the "," in the Double string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to parseDouble with comma as decimal separator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323599/best-way-to-parsedouble-with-comma-as-decimal-separator)

Answer (score 2):

If there is no way to get rid of comma(,) you may use another approach:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
Number number = format.parse("40,123.012345678901");
double d = number.doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to remove comma:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("40,123.012345678901".replace(",", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

A `double` is limited to around 16 digits of precision.  If you need more precision, you should use BigDecimal.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("40,123.012345678901".replace(",", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the comma (,) from your string:

This will work:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("40123.012345678901");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NumberFormat` to get `double` value,

```
    try {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        Number parse = format.parse("40,123.012345678901");
        System.out.println(parse.doubleValue());
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Careful.  `double` is not infinitely large.  10 or more decimals starts to cut down on the size of the integer portion.   Indeed, even the string `40123.012345678901` in the question does not completely roundtrip:

```java
public static void show(String s) {
    double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
    System.out.printf("[%s] [%f] [%.15f]\n", s, d, d);
}

show("40123.012345678901");
[40123.012345678901] [40123.012346] [40123.012345678900000] // lost the 1.
show("40123.0123456789012345");
[40123.0123456789012345] [40123.012346] [40123.012345678900000] // lost 12345

show("4.0123456789012345"); // less integer digits:
[4.0123456789012345] [4.012346] [4.012345678901235]  // we picked up 12345 again!

show("123456789.0123456789012345"); 
[123456789.0123456789012345] [123456789.012346] [123456789.012345670000000]  // lost 9012345!
```