# Read double from .txt file

Tags: java, file

I have a .txt file where data are written like this:

> ZONEIDFROM;ZONEIDTO;DISTANCETYPE;FACILITYID;DISTANCE;
>   1;2;C;HF;9,416667;

I want to return the distance if zoneidfrom = 1 and zoneidto = 2.

Everything seems to be okay in my code except for the distance which is a double.

```
public void Load(String filename, int zoneidfrom, int zoneidto, String mode) throws Exception{
    queue.clear();
    int from,to;
    double dist;
    String c_or_l;

    BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String ligne = br.readLine(); //First line read
    while(ligne != null){
        ligne = br.readLine(); //First line read
        String [] tab = ligne.split(";");
        ArrayList<Double> d = new ArrayList<>();
        d.add(Double.parseDouble(ligne));
        from = Integer.parseInt(tab[0]);
        to = Integer.parseInt(tab[1]);
        c_or_l = tab[2];
        dist = d.get(4);

        if(zoneidfrom == from && zoneidto == to && c_or_l.equals(mode));{
            distance(dist);
        }
    }      
}
public double distance(double db_distance){
    return db_distance;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your code is not parsing the correct string value for the double. You should be parsing `tab[4]`, not the whole line.

Secondly, the double value contains a comma for the decimal separator. `Double.parseDouble()` does not take Locale into account.

You should use a `NumberFormat` to parse the double, while using an appropriate `Locale`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4323628/481248) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

ligne is string and it will be "1;2;C;HF;9,416667;" in first while loop, now you are trying to parse it to double , obviously it will throw number format exception .
For distance to get you have to do, Double.parseDouble(tab[4].replace(",","."))