# How to perform mathematical operation on numbers in java having comma instead of decimal?

Tags: java, type-conversion, numbers, number-formatting

Say i have 2 strings "123,21" and "22,41" i want to subtract both these numbers and return the output in String format itself in Java.

I am unable to identify how can i use Number.format() to do this.

Also how can i convert this string to big decimal?

Comment: You need to parse the number with [a locale that supports comma as the decimal separator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can follow this way to use [Number.format()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4323628/10524205).

Then, you can simply create [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) with the double result.

After various exchange via comments, this is my final answer, allowing to control decimal separator, and grouping separator:

```
public static final BigDecimal convertToBigDecimal(String stringNumber1, String stringNumber2, char separator, char groupingSeparator)
            throws ParseException {
        Locale myLocale = Locale.FRANCE;
        DecimalFormatSymbols decimalSeparator = new DecimalFormatSymbols(myLocale);
        decimalSeparator.setDecimalSeparator(separator);
        decimalSeparator.setGroupingSeparator(groupingSeparator);
        DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance(myLocale);
        format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalSeparator);

        Number number1 = format.parse(stringNumber1.trim());
        Number number2 = format.parse(stringNumber2.trim());
        double substractResult = number1.doubleValue() - number2.doubleValue();

        // If you want back a String presentation => String stringFormat = "" +
        // substractResult;

        return new BigDecimal(substractResult);
    }
```

This way you fully control locale and decimal separator as you wish.

If you want to use coma as default decimal separator, you can add this overload:

```
public final BigDecimal convertToBigDecimal(String stringNumber1, String stringNumber2)
            throws ParseException {
        return convertToBigDecimal(stringNumber1, stringNumber2, ',', '.');
    }

    public final BigDecimal convertToBigDecimal(String stringNumber1, String stringNumber2, char separator)
            throws ParseException {
        return convertToBigDecimal(stringNumber1, stringNumber2, separator, '.');
    }
```

You can then easily use this new function

```
System.out.println(convertToBigDecimal("123,21", "22,41", ','));
System.out.println(convertToBigDecimal("123.21", "22.41", '.'));
System.out.println(convertToBigDecimal("123,441.33", "122,441.22", '.', ','));
System.out.println(convertToBigDecimal("59.998,50", "698,43", ',', '.'));
System.out.println(convertToBigDecimal("59.998,50", "49.998,50", ','));
```

Comment: Hi, does it solve your issue?

Comment: Hey @Bsquare thanks for the help! 
Everything works good except i get this exception: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: " 1 "

Comment: See, you have an heading, and trailing space characters at the beginning of " 1 "; you should use trim() method on String, before trying to parse them.

Comment: i guess there is still something missing!
for the above code in locale Locale.FRANCE
while trying to subtract 59.998,5 and 1.399,99 i get output as 58.
basically it removes everything after "." and does a 59-1=58
So basically the problem still persists!

Comment: You should use DecimalFormat instead of Number Format, and define the wanted symbol to be Culture indépendant. I'll update my answer as soon as I m back on my computer 

Comment: Cool!
I am playing around with DecimalFormat, but i am yet unable to find a generic fix which handles all use cases like:

1.     123,441.33 - 122,441.22 = 1000.11
2.      59.998,50 - 698,43 = 599260.07
3.      59.998,50 - 49.998,50 = 10000

Comment: Done ... I wrote you an utility method allowing you to control everything, and matching all situation ;)

Comment: I updated with grouping separator management. Does it solve your issue?

Comment: looks amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

I think decimal format with this custom formatting can be provided to convert the text to an integer or double as per requirement.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {                                            
     String text1 = "123,21";                                                                              
     String text2 = "22,41";                                                                               
     NumberFormat nf_in = new DecimalFormat("###,##");                                                     
     int number1 = nf_in.parse(text1).intValue();                                                          

     System.out.println("Number 1 "+number1);                                                              

     int number2 = nf_in.parse(text2).intValue();                                                          

     System.out.println("Number2 "+number2);                                                               

     System.out.println("Subtract Number2 from number 1"+ (number1-number2));                              
 }
```

Comment: But the OP wants to treat comma as decimal separator, which is not what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String text1 = "123,21";
        String text2 = "22,41";


        DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        decimalFormatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        NumberFormat nf_in = new DecimalFormat("##,##",decimalFormatSymbols);

        double number1 = nf_in.parse(text1).doubleValue();

        System.out.println("Number 1 "+number1*1);

        double number2 = nf_in.parse(text2).doubleValue();

        System.out.println("Number2 "+number2*1);

        double outputvalue = number1 - number2;


        System.out.println( outputvalue);
    }
```

I think using DecimalFormatSymbols with Decimal format should do allow you to use comma as the decimal symbol.

Refer [Best way to parseDouble with comma as decimal separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323599/best-way-to-parsedouble-with-comma-as-decimal-separator)

Answer (score -1):

You maybe want to values next to comma and subtract them. A common and a handy way I know is using split() method that will return an array of strings.

```
String text = "123,21";
String[] values = text.split(","); //this will add all the strings before or after a ",".
String answer = (Integer.parseInt(values[0])-Integer.parseInt(values[1])).toString();
System.out.println("Answer: "+answer); //will output 102
```

Comment: But OP wants to subtract `123,21` and `22,41` as decimals. The question is not about doing `123 - 21`.