# Parse string to float/double

Tags: java, database, parsing, double

I am getting values from jTable and putting it in my DataBase (MySQL). In my DB table there is column PAYMENT that is double. When I try to put values from my jTable there is a problem with it:

```
String payment=(String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2);
double pay=double .parseDouble (payment);
........
pst.setDouble(3, zar);
```

I am getting this exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "84,21834324"

How can I put this column from jTable as double in my DB table?
P.S.: I tried with float too.

Comment: You know the culprit is **`,`**, right?

Comment: Yes and I assume that it is expecting dot .

Comment: @SirFartALot Absolutely nothing with that post.

Comment: What is "zar" in the statement `pst.setDouble(3, zar);` ? Is it some other string or a double value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `,` with a `.`:

```
String payment = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(row, 2);
double pay = Double.parseDouble(payment.replace(",". "."));
........
pst.setDouble(3, zar);
```

Edit -- If you want to support more complex values:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.text.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String v1 = "84,21834324";
    String v2 = "1.234.567,89";

    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    Number n1 = format.parse(v1);
    Number n2 = format.parse(v2);

    double d1 = n1.doubleValue();
    double d2 = n2.doubleValue();
  }
}
```

[Lifted the edited solution from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323599/best-way-to-parsedouble-with-comma-as-decimal-separator)

Comment: Actually this works in my case. I have only one separator.

Comment: @SirFartALot what double value would you expect for 1.234.567,89 ?

Comment: dblStr = "1.234.567,89";
DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN).parse(dblStr) --> 1234567.89d
DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).parse(dblStr) --> 1.234d