# Convert String to Integer/Float/Double

Tags: java, android

I am trying to convert a string to `Integer/Float/Double` but I got a `NumberFormatException`.

My String is `37,78584`, Now I am converting this to any of them I got `NumberFormatException`.

How can I convert this `string` to any of them.

Please help me to get out of this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285982/parsedouble-in-java-results-to-numberformatexception

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use the appropriate locale for the number like

```
String s = "37,78584";
Number number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRENCH).parse(s);
double d= number.doubleValue();
System.out.println(d);
```

prints

```
37.78584
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `,` by `""` blank in string and then convert your numbers

```
String str = "37,78584";
str = str.replaceAll("\\,","");
```

Comment: Using the proper locale is a better approach. And you need go replace the comma with a period, not a blank.

Answer (score 1):

Check the String value

that

```
if(String .equals(null or ""){

} else{
    //Change to integer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using methods like `Type.parseSomething` and `Type.valueOf` isn't a best choice, because their behavior depends from locale. For example in some languages decimal delimiter is '.' symbol when in other ','. Therefore in some systems code works fine in other it crashes and throw exceptions. The more appropriate way is use formatters. JDK and Android SDK has many ready to use formatters for many purposes which is locale-independent. Have a look at [NumberFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use a Locale which uses a comma as the separator, such as French locale:

```
double d = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRENCH).parse("37,78584").doubleValue();
```

The fastest approach is just to substitute any commas with periods.

```
double d = String.parseDouble("37,78584".replace(",","."));
```

Answer (score 0):

do this before parsing to remove the commas:

```
myString.replaceAll(",", "")​;
```

Answer (score 0):

First Remove `,` this, using below code

```
String s= "37,78584";
s=s.replaceAll(",", "");
```

And then use below code

For String to Integer:-

```
Integer.parseInt(s);
```

For String to Float:-

```
Float.parseFloat(s);
```

For String to Double:-

```
Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace '

```
String value  = "23,87465";
int value1 = Integer.parseInt(value.toString().replaceAll("[^0-9.]",""));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing the `,` and then converting into an Integer/float/double

```
String mysting="37,78584";
String newString=myString.replace(",", "");
int value=Integer.parseInt(newString);
```