# Double data Type Parse "NaN" as "NaN" Why?

Tags: java, nan

I'm parsing the "NaN" value in to double and it is giving me as "NaN".

```
double  d = Double.parseDouble("NaN");
System.out.println(d);
```

It is printing the "NaN" value. I am surprised because I would [expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285982/parsedouble-in-java-results-to-numberformatexception) that parsing a non-number for a double would result in `NumberFormatException` in Java.

Can anyone explain why the parse succeeded, and what was really stored in the variable?

Comment: What would you expect it to be?

Comment: I think that this is a reasonable Java question, not a very poor Javascript question.  Edited accordingly.

Comment: It's sad that this was closed - it has a single, unambiguous answer that hinges on the relevant Java and IEEE specs, and is extremely constructive if you've never seen this edge case before.

What a way to discourage a new user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are probably surprised that this special value could have been stored in a `double` variable.  This is because Java uses the IEEE 754 standard for floating point representation.

This standard allows to represent not just specific rational numbers, but also a few special values, like plus infinity or minus infinity, which are essentially very big numbers - results of calculations that yielded bigger results than any representable rational value.  (There are also denormal numbers, lying somewhere between the finite and infinite values; precision of those is reduced compared to the precision you are used to, but not so extremely as with the infinities.  The loss of precision is caused by giving more room to the exponent at the expense of the mantissa.)

However, a `NaN` is not an infinity, nor an indicator of an overflow or an underflow.  It is not an inaccurate result of any computation.  It is a non-value, similar to a `NULL` in the database.  In fact, try this in your program:

```
System.out.println(d == d)
```

It will print out `false`.

Why false?  Loosely speaking, if you do not *know* the values of two quantities, there is no reason to assume that they are the same value.  They usually are not.

It is actually quite unusual to see a `NaN` on input to `double.ParseDouble`, except during some kind of unmarshalling.

Comment: Perfect answer. Also, I was really happy to learn that `(d == d)` could actually return false ! Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

[NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) is not a number.

```
"NaN" stands for "not a number". "Nan" is produced if a 
floating point operation has some input parameters that cause the 
operation to produce some undefined result. For example, 0.0 divided 
by 0.0 is arithmetically undefined. Taking the square root of a negative 
number is also undefined.
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, "NaN" is "Not a Number", and a valid value for a double.

So, if you parse "NaN", it seems logical to get "NaN" as a result.

You should take a look at [In Java, what does NaN mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618059/in-java-what-does-nan-mean)

Comment: Yes. it is straight forward explanation and I also know that. but you did not really understand my question. it is *what was really stored in the variable?* I mean so in this cas variable "d" will store "NaN" as string value or what ?

Answer (score 1):

Because "NaN" is Not A Number.
[`Double.parseDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) expects a double value in string format