# keyEvents not working for jTextField

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to change the value in a jTextField when I press the UP and DOWN arrow keys on the keyboard. When UP is pressed the value goes up by a set amount and when DOWN is pressed it goes down.

This is what I so far:

```
private void engineTxtKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 

    try{
    int code = evt.getKeyCode();
    double value = Double.parseDouble(engineTxt.getText());
    if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        value = value + 25.00;
        if ((value) > 100.00) {
            value = 100.00;
            engineTxt.setText(String.format("%.2f", value));
        }
    }
    else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        value = value - 25.00;
        if ((value) < 0.00) {
            value = 0.00;
            engineTxt.setText(String.format("%.2f", value));
        }
    }
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}
```

Before I put the try/catch in there, the error I got was:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,00"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
```

The list goes all the way down for many lines, basically it would flag anything with parsing and formats throughout the process.

The thing is that I have the same parsing for another 10 TextFields and there is no problem, but this is the only one with a keyEvent. After adding the try/catch I get my sout() message every time i press a key and the rest of the program continues just fine.

Comment: Looks like your problem is the parseDouble() method, not the keyboard events.

Comment: In this case the input probably was `0,00` (from error log) for which you will get `NumberFormatException` while parsing. Did you try with other values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parseDouble in Java results to NumberFormatException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285982/parsedouble-in-java-results-to-numberformatexception).

Comment: Other values meaning without `,` (comma), just plain numbers.

Comment: those values in the textfield are put by a double Random. When i parse them in other textfields it works. I even tried with a simple "0" but the error pops whenever i press the key. And it even pops when I press a different key other than UP or DOWN

Comment: If it is so, then I am afraid there is no way to suggest anything without seeing the full code.
I think despite using Random, *somehow* the textfield is getting set with value containing `,`. But cant tell surely without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get to the line :

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(engineTxt.getText());
```

The string `engineTxt.getText()` returns `(String) 0,00`, which raises an error.

While

```
double value = Double.parseDouble("0");
System.out.println(value);
```

Wont raise an exception,

```
double value = Double.parseDouble("0,00");
System.out.println(value);
```

does.

Somewhere along the line, there is a `,` that should'nt be there.
Since this will work:

```
double value = Double.parseDouble("0.05");
System.out.println(value);
```

**EDIT:**

> Like someone said in the comments, while the OP is not aware of it, it is a *Possible* duplicate of [parseDouble in Java results to NumberFormatException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285982/parsedouble-in-java-results-to-numberformatexception)

Comment: *Possible Duplicate*, not *Duplicate* yet.

Comment: @minarmahmud Well, yes, _Possible_ ... But the KeyEvent is working, and the error is due to the same problem.