# Convert String (representing decimal number) to long

Tags: java, string, parsing, converters, long-integer

I've googled around a bit but could not find examples to find a solution. Here is my problem:

```
String s = "100.000";
long l = Long.parseLong(s);
```

The 2nd line of code which tries to parse the string 's' into a long throws a **NumberFormatException**.

Is there a way around this? the problem is the string representing the decimal number is actually time in milliseconds so I cannot cast it to int because I lose precision.

Comment: what that dot stands for? is it separator between 0's or decimal mark?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a BigDecimal to handle the double parsing (without the risk of precision loss that you might get with `Double.parseDouble()`):

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(s);
long value = bd.longValue();
```

Answer (score 4):

as i don't know is your 100.000 equals 100 or 100 000
i think safest solution which i can recommend you will be:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
Number number = nf.parse("100.000");
long l = number.longValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

'long' is an integer type, so the String parse is rejected due to the decimal point.  Selecting a more appropriate type may help, such as a double.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888088/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-double-in-java-using-a-specific-locale

Comment: Yeah, I realized a bit late that this may be European notation.  I may just delete this answer, as it seems others have covered the gamut of good possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all spaceholders for the thousands, the dot...

```
s.replaceAll(".","");
```

Comment: this would result in wrong number, 100.00 would be 10000

Answer (score 0):

You should use NumberFormat to parse the values

Answer (score 0):

We can use regular expression to trim out the decimal part. Then use parseLong

Long.parseLong( data.replaceAll("\..*", ""));

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to loose presision then you should use `multiplication`

```
    BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("100.111");
    long l = (long) (bigDecimal.doubleValue() * 1000);<--Multiply by 1000 as it
                                                         is miliseconds
    System.out.println(l);
```

Output:

```
100111
```

Comment: This is an extremely bad idea. Doubles are not lossless! Following this advice will likely lead to data corruption.