# JAVA: How do you convert a String variable to a Double variable?

Tags: java, string, parsing, variables, double

I'm writing a program that is dealing with about 150 different variables, which I have extracted off a webpage. I was looking at how to change them into a double variable, so that I can compare them later in the program, and found this code to do so:

```
String text = "12.34"; // example String
double value = Double.parseDouble(text);
```

This works fine for some of them, but a lot of the numbers that I'm extracting from the webpage as a String variable come in the form '1,200.000', with the comma (,) to separate the number into thousands.

As a result, the program will not allow me to run the above code on them, because of that comma (,). How do I get rid of the comma, and hence change these Strings, like 1,200.000, into a double variable, like 1200.000?

Comment: You need locale aware parsing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888088/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-double-in-java-using-a-specific-locale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily get rid of the comma :

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(text.replace(",",""));
```

Note that this will only work if comma's are used for the thousand separator. Other locales may switch the command and dot around.

Comment: Will I  be able to use that even if some of the numbers do not have commas, or will it return an error?

Comment: @Eran In French (and most of EU if I'm not mistaken) the thousand separator and the decimal separator are switched.

Comment: @owlstead What makes you think the OP cares about French locale? They only asked about getting rid of the comma.

Answer (score 0):

First just delete the commas from the `String` and then `parse` it into `Double`:

```
String text = text.replace(",", "");
double val = Double.parseDouble(text);
```

Note that this will only work if comma's are used for the thousand separator. Other locales may switch the command and dot around.