# setting locale for each variable in java

Tags: java, parsing, double, locale

Hello ive got some problem with my program. I try to reading lines from file ,split them to each variable. But this file have different types of double like:

- 10000,20
- 4000,10
- 5,400.20

and when i trying to parse strings to double ive got exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10000,20"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `comma(,)` in  "10000,20" so remove comma and try

```
 Double.parseDouble("10000,20".replace(",", ""))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but here is better solution  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888088/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-double-in-java-using-a-specific-locale