# java, convert string to double for any locale

Tags: java, android

I know that there is already a similar question about this, but this one is a bit different.

Say we have a string, and we know it can be converted to a double, but we know nothing about the locale of it.  Maybe its locale is English (with dot as separator) or French (with comma as separator), or something else.

So, how do I convert it to the right double value?

Comment: You can't if you don't know the locale beforehand. "100,100" is a thousand times more in English than it is in French.

Comment: you are right if we must get the double value accurately

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse a number from the "users" (default) locale, then maybe this could help you:

```
double number = java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(stringNumber).doubleValue();
```

Comment: This method takes a string value of "0.001" to 1.0 in French Canada locale

Answer (score 0):

I suppose if you wanted to brute force it, you could loop through [NumberFormat.getAvailableLocales()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getAvailableLocales()) and call NumberFormat.getInstance() for each one as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888088/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-double-in-java-using-a-specific-locale)