# How to store a value in variable as a double from user input?

Tags: java, variables, input, double

I've only just started learning programming in Java and I cannot figure out how to store a value from user input as a double.

Here's my code:

```
    package FirstProject;
    
       import java.util.Scanner;
    
       public class TripPlanner {
           
           public static void main () {
           Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print("How many " + currencySymbol + " are there in 1 USD? ");
           double conversion = console.nextDouble();
           }
       }
```

I don't understand why when I enter, for example 19.5, it gives me exception error. My understanding is that I defined the conversion variable as double (double conversion) and I expect the user to enter a double (console.nextDouble();). It's fundamental but coming from Python I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Could you please always add what error exactly you are getting?

Comment: This is the error I get:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
 at DoubleProblem.main(DoubleProblem.java:10)

Answer (score 2):

Using the Scanner like you did is somewhat uncontrolled. For example, the format the scanner expects is locale-dependent. If your system settings are German, for example, then you need to enter `3,7` for a double value of `3.7`.

If the format of the entered string is invalid, then an exception will be thrown, probably `java.util.InputMismatchException`. You should catch the exception and react in a way that's fit to you use case.

To get better control over the locale used, you should instead read a string from the console and then for example use a `java.text.NumberFormat`.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888088/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-double-in-java-using-a-specific-locale).

Answer (score 1):

@Leisetreter pointed me in the right direction. It was the keyboard settings. I live in the UK and use the conventions of writing a decimal number with a dot. However, my keyboard was set to Polish programmer's. In Poland decimal numbers are written with a ",". Once I changed the settings I did not have that problem anymore. It would have never occurred to me. Thanks @Leisetreter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mistake in your code. Except from main.
The proper way you should call her is `public static void main (String args[])`